# Null Validation in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

```
@item.qmsCallAudit.Employee.EmployeeProcesses
     .Select(e=> e.Employee1.employee_code).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
```

How to check null for e.Employee1.employee_code

Comment: wat  is the data type of e.Employee1.employee_code??

Comment: Do you want to check e.Employee1 for null reference?

Comment: Note that `SingleOrDefault()` is going to return `null` if your query returns more than one value, which is fairly likely with no `Where()` call, is that the intended behavior?

Comment: @Namfuak: Its going to throw an exception if the query returns more than one value.

Comment: @Chris Huh, never noticed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var result = item.qmsCallAudit.Employee.EmployeeProcesses
 .Where(e => e.Employee1 != null && e.Employee1.employee_code != null)
 .Select(e=> e.Employee1.employee_code)
 .SingleOrDefault();

var code = result != null ? result.ToString() : null;
```

Don't `ToString()` after `SingleOrDefault()` it can return null and then it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
@item.qmsCallAudit.Employee.EmployeeProcesses.Where(e => e.Employee1.employee_code != null).Select(e => e.Employee1.employee_code).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
```

Try this ^^